# The antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x-ib}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I know if my domain $D_{\mathbb{R}}\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $b$ is a real constant, then:

$$\int_{D_\mathbb{R}}\dfrac{1}{x-ib}\mathrm{dx}=\ln(|x-ib|)$$

But if my domain $D_{\mathbb{C}}\subset\mathbb{C}$:

$$\int_{D_\mathbb{C}}\frac{1}{x-ib}\mathrm{dx}=\log(x-ib)=\ln|x-ib|+i\mathrm{arg}(z)$$

This feels a bit counterintuitive to me, but is it correct?

Comment: If you say that $D \subset \mathbb R$ is a domain, then what does $D\in\mathbb R$ mean underneath your integral?

Comment: @simon i edited it, does it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the complex case, even for real domain, do not use $|\cdot|$. **That is incorrect**.
Correct is: [some branch of] $\log(x-ib)$.

*Example*
Computed numerically, we have to $10$ decimals
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x-i}\;dx \approx 0.3465735903 + i\; 0.7853981634
$$
But
$$
\log\big(|x-i|\big)\Big|_{x=0}^{x=1} = \log\big(|1-i|\big) - \log\big(|-i|\big)
= \log(\sqrt2) - \log(1)  \approx 0.3465735903
$$
**incorrect**.

On the other hand,
$$
\log(1-i) - \log(-i) = \big(\log\big(\sqrt2\big) - \frac{i\pi}{4}\big) - \big(\frac{-i\pi}{2}\big) = \log\big(\sqrt{2}\big) + \frac{i\pi}{4} \approx 0.3465735903 + i\;0.7853981635
$$
**correct**
I used a branch of $\log$ that is continuous on the line segment from $1-i$ to $-i$.

NOTE.  When you ask Maple or Mathematica for $\int \frac{dx}{x}$ they give you $\log (x)$ and not $\log\big(|x|\big)$.  This is (one of) the reasons.  The "answer" $\log\big(|x|\big)$ is just wrong in many cases.

Comment: i'm sorry could you put parentheses around the syntactical arguments of log(something)

Comment: Done.  But note that in mathemtics it is comon to write $\log x$ or $\sin x$ and so on.

Comment: Thank you! I'm aware. Just to clarify, in the first case you just ignored the i(argument) part, right?

Comment: Actually for a while i was under the impression that the modulus function just changes the real part, not takes the 'length' of a vector...

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, since $D\subset\mathbb R$, we know that $D$ is an interval such as $(a,b)$ with $a<b$ since $D$ is connected.

This means the first integral becomes
$$
\int_{D_\mathbb{R}}\dfrac{1}{x-ib}\mathrm{dx}=\ln(|x-ib|)\Bigg|_{x=a}^b.
$$

For the integral over $\mathbb C$: Look up the definition of the complex logarithm function first (on Wikipedia or any standard textbook). You'll find that there is no unique logarithm function.

Comment: If you are proficient in Complex Analysis would you please look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4058484/multiplying-out-by-a-minus-sign-under-an-absolute-value-function) of mine?